# Evitar que estado seja perdido ao usar history.push() - react-router-dom - ReactJS

Tags: react, react-router, react-router-dom

Tenho um componente que faz uma chamada para API e armazena o retorno no estado para exibir para o usuário. Porém, quando uso o `history.push()` para navegar para outra página da aplicação e em seguida uso o `history.goBack()` o estado do componente carregado anteriormente é perdido e uma nova request para API é feita. Como faço para que esses dados não sejam perdidos?

Estou utilizando o `react-router-dom` para gerenciar minhas rotas.

Comment: você provavelmente teria q fazer o `storage` dos dados pra conseguir restaurar o estado quando o usuário voltar para a página, nesse caso existem varias formas de fazer, você pode implementar um esquema de storage usando `localStorage` ou `sessionStorage`, mas caso necessite de uma estratégia de cache mais elaborada sugiro dar uma olhada no `react-query`

Comment: Olha sem ver o código é meio difícil, mas recomendaria utilizar uma context e dentro dela colocar as paginas que foram navegadas em um Array, e assim acrescentando a cada alteração de pagina, e quando querer voltar uma pagina para trás pegue o penultimo elemento do Array